# CUPS - How to show the paper size of a queued job?

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, cups, ipp

I am troubleshooting my Raspberry Pi CUPS printer server which is having trouble printing a specific paper size from my Fedora laptop. My printer, connected via USB to my CUPS server, cuts off documents of size 8.5x13 inches. However, this only happens with my laptop with Fedora specifically. Other devices in my network can print the same document size fine.

I am suspecting that either my laptop or my Raspberry Pi processes the document size incorrectly. I just need to confirm it. However, the CUPS GUI (through the web interface) does not seem to display the paper size of a specific print job. Is there any way too see the paper size of a queued print job through the command line?

Comment: this suggestion is coming from general linux knowledge ... check for a CUPS log file ... if it exists, it may contain useful info ... also, CUPS may store job info in temporary files

Comment: Look in `/var/spool/cups/`. The `c####` (where `#` is a digit) is the control file, and `d#####-001` (same number) is the data to be printed. Also, install `wireshark` and you can watch the CUPS conversation on the network. Also check `/var/logs/cups/` for helpful information.

Comment: You may want to specify a `PageLogFormat` _format string_ that includes `%{media}` so the page size is recorded in the page log.  Note that the page log might be in `/var/log/cups/page_log` or possibly in the systemd journal (`journalctl -u cups -e`) depending on your system.